# Firestore OR query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Imagine I have a collection in Firestore with objects of the following format:

```js
{
  /* ... */
  ownerId: "id-1",
  memberIds: [
    "id-2",
    "id-3",
    "id-4"
  ]
}
```

How can I query Firestore for all documents where the string `id-1` is present in the `ownerId` field **OR** the `memberIds` field?

I only found AND queries, like so:

```js
return collection('whatever')
  .where('memberIds', 'array-contains', 'id-1')
  .where('ownerId', '==', 'id-1');
```

But those will only return me the documents where `id-1` is included in **both** the `ownerId` field and the `memberIds` array.

I understand that I could perform multiple queries and join the results, but that would make pagination and ordering too much of a hassle to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Update of March 16, 2023, when the JS SDK Version 9.18.0 was released

Since the release of the [JS SDK Version 9.18.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_9180_-_march_16_2023) it is now possible to execute [`OR` queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries).

So you can do as follows:

```
const colRef = collection(db, 'whatever')
const q = query(
  colRef,
  or(
    where('memberIds', 'array-contains', 'id-1'),
    where('ownerId', '==', 'id-1')
  )
)

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

##### Previous answer

It's not possible in Firestore to execute an OR query like the one you describe.

One solution is to denormalize your data (a very common approach in the NoSQL world) and add, to the document, an extra field which "concatenates" the two other fields, as follows:

```
{
  /* ... */
  ownerId: "id-1",
  memberIds: [
    "id-2",
    "id-3",
    "id-4"
  ],
  ownersAndMemberIds: [
    "id-1", 
    "id-2",
    "id-3",
    "id-4"
  ]
}
```

Then you can easily query the doc with

```
return collection('whatever')
  .where('ownersAndMemberIds', 'array-contains', 'id-1');
```

---

Of course it requires that you maintain this array aligned with the other fields, but this is not difficult. Either you do it from your front-end when you update one of the two "main" fields, or through a Cloud Function which is triggered on any change to the doc.

Comment: The Cloud Function approach is a very good idea, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Firestore now supports [OR queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries) (in preview). You can use it from Firebase JS SDK [`v9.18.0`](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_9180_-_march_16_2023).

```
const colRef = collection(db, 'whatever')
const q = query(
  colRef,
  or(
    where('memberIds', 'array-contains', 'mem1'),
    where('ownerId', '==', 'mem1')
  )
)

const snapshot = await getDocs(q)
console.log(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })))
```